# What is intptr_t,is it a type for integer or pointer?

Tags: c, linux

It's defined in `/usr/include/stdint.h`:

```
typedef long int                intptr_t;
```

is it supposed to be a type for integer or pointer?

Comment: @Chris Lutz ,how ? `man intptr_t` doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: I believe there's a manpage for `stdint.h`. And there's always Google.

Answer (score 30):

It is a signed integer type that is big enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the holding pointer part meas that it will probably be a different size on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms ...

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why is it necessary to have a signed and an unsigned version of [u]intptr_t ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a signed integer type that guaranteed to can hold a `void*` type.

And why there is also `[u]intptr_t`? Because:

> Any valid pointer to void can be converted to `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`
>   and back with no change in value. The C Standard
>   guarantees that a pointer to void may be converted to or from a
>   pointer to any object type and back again and that the result must
>   compare equal to the original pointer. Consequently, converting
>   directly from a `char *` pointer to a `uintptr_t` is allowed on implementations that support the `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Where is this quoted from?

Comment: You got me. Here: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT36-C.+Converting+a+pointer+to+integer+or+integer+to+pointer