# Two pointer representation dilemma

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I don't understand how a machine can have more than one pointer representation. [The following](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Null-Pointer-Constant.html) from GNU says

> if the target machine has two different pointer representations, the
>   compiler won't know which representation to use for that argument.

How is it possible? What is the relationship between the saying and `#define SEM_FAILED ((sem_t*)-1)`? What does the latter do? I know it is null pointer which has constant value. But how is it represented in a memory since it points to -1? What about if it points to a right location?

Comment: The rest of your question is too involved for me to answer right now, but I want to address one particular misconception: `(sem_t*)-1` is _not_ a null pointer.  It is the result of casting a _nonzero_ integer constant to a pointer type; this produces a pointer with an implementation-defined _non-null_ value.  Whether it points to an object is also implementation-defined.  (Pointers can be non-null but still not point to an object.)

Comment: A pointer to `long` need not be able to represent mis-aligned addresses (`address % sizeof(long) != 0`) at all. But a pointer to `char` (or a pointer to void, which is constrained to the same representation) must be able to designate every single byte.

Comment: I've worked on computers that did not have byte addresses so a char * representation was different than int *.

Comment: This is why the cast in `printf("%p", (void*)myPtr)` is used.

Comment: @zwol: in addition to your remark, Does `int x = 0; void *p = (void *)x;` make `p` a null pointer? one that compares equal in `p == NULL`?

Comment: @zwol what about `(sem_t)0`?

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, at least for the recent C versions. I *think* since C99.

Comment: @alk: I searched the C Standard for an answer and did not find one... Do you have a quote?

Comment: @chqrlie: For C11 please see [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) and [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p4).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13306914/694576

Comment: @alk: yes of course, the definition of a null pointer is *An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.66) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.* But this only applies to a constant expression, which is not the case of `(void *)x`.

Comment: @alk: All other cases are covered by *An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation* So `(void *)x` might not be a null pointer, and thus would not compare equal to `NULL` or `0`.

Comment: @concurrencyboy Did you mean `(sem_t *)0` ?  That is a null pointer (with type pointer-to-`sem_t`).  There are no requirements in POSIX for what `sem_t` actually is, so `(sem_t)0` could be a null pointer, could just be a number, or could be an invalid cast, depending on the concrete type of `sem_t`.

Comment: @chqrlie I was going to quote the same text you did: it is implementation-defined whether `int x = 0; void *p = (void *)x` sets `p` to a null pointer.  You've now made me wonder whether I was right, earlier, to say that `void *p = (void *)-1` is guaranteed to produce a _non-null_ pointer.  It might be time for a language-lawyer question.

Comment: @zwol the value of `(sem_t*)-1` is implementation-defined. The implementation might define it to be a null pointer or anything else

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is alluding to the "near" and "far" pointers found on some 16-bit architectures?  From what I understand, they used different offset scalings to work around being stuck with just 64kb of address space.

Comment: It is not that one.

Answer (score 1):

One of the very first architectures that C targeted were some with 36-bit or 18-bit words words (the type `int`). Only the words were directly addressable at addresses like 0, 1, 2 using the native pointers. However one word for one character would have wasted too much memory, so a 9-bit `char` type was added, with 2 or 4 characters in one word. Since these would not have been addressable by the word pointer, `char *` was made from two words: one pointing to the word, and another telling which of the bytes within the word should be manipulated.

Of course now the problem is that `char *` is two words wide, whereas `int *` is just one, and this matters when calling a function without prototype or with ellipsis - while `(void*)0` would have a representation compatible with `(char *)0`, it wouldn't be compatible with `(int *)0`, hence an explicit cast is required.

---

There is another problem with `NULL`. While GCC seems to assure that `NULL` will be of type `void *`, the C standard does not guarantee that, so even using `NULL` in a function call like `execl` that expects `char *`s as variable arguments is wrong without a cast, because an implementation can define

```
#define NULL 0
```

---

`(sem_t*)-1` is not a NULL pointer, it is the integer `-1` converted to pointer with *implementation-defined* results. On POSIX systems it will (by necessity) result in an address that can never be a location of any `sem_t`.

It is actually a really bad convention to use `-1` here since the resulting address most likely doesn't have a *correct alignment* for `sem_t`, so the entire construct has undefined behaviour in itself.