# C pointer address manipulation

Tags: c, pointers

There is a basic problem which I've had to use the below logic to fix.
I want to know how to make this work.

```
void main(void)
{
     unsigned char data[100];
     unsigned int i;
     uint32_t data_addr;
     uint32_t *p;

     for(i=0;i<100;i++)
         data[i] = i;

     data_addr = (uint32_t) &data[16];
     p = (uint32_t *) data_addr;
     // p = &data[16];
     printf("\nAddress = %#x %#x \n", *p, (data + 16));
     printf("\n");
     return (0);
}
```

I know for a fact `p = (uint32_t *) data_addr;` does not work; but I have a situation to make this code work with the same statement.

I would like to know how to make it work without using `p = &data[16];`.

Comment: To make work what? What are you trying to do? What doesn't work?

Comment: Your code will not work on 64-bit systems, so use `unsigned long long int` or simply `uint64_t`. What exacly is not working? It's fine with GNU GCC compiler. Could you please provide some compiler response or your output?

Comment: @FalconUA better yet, `uintptr_t`…

Comment: No `void main(void)`, please. The prototype is `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char**)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior. I presume you know that and are ignoring that technicality. But to be clear, converting pointers to ints and back is usually not a good idea, and casting pointers from one type to another (so-called **type punning**) is [very much not a good idea](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/04/using-pointers-to-recast-in-c-is-bad.html).

That said, this code will not work on a 64-bit system with 64-bit pointers. You can't store a 64-bit address in a 32-bit integer. If your operating system is 64-bit—which is most likely the case these days—then you'll need `uint64_t` instead of `uint32_t`. Or, better yet, use [`intptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410294/what-is-intptr-t-is-it-a-type-for-integer-or-pointer), an integer type that is large enough to hold a pointer.

```
 #include <stdint.h>

 data_addr = (intptr_t) &data[16];
 p = (uint32_t *) data_addr;
```

And again, this roundabout conversion from `unsigned char *` to `uint32_t *`
is *not safe*. You do not know the alignment of `data`. If it is not 32-bit aligned then `&data[16]` could be an **improperly aligned** address for a 32-bit int and could crash some systems. x86 architectures are forgiving of mis-aligned data accesses; other architectures are not.

Type punning also introduces **aliasing** problems. Compilers are allowed to assume pointers to unrelated types point to unrelated objects, and thereby make optimizations that will break when those pointers actually refer to the same object.

**See:** [Type punning isn't funny: Using pointers to recast in C is bad.](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/04/using-pointers-to-recast-in-c-is-bad.html)

(Also, you should use `%p` to print pointers, not `%x`.)

Comment: Thank you. You are right about the point. How do I get over this without getting segmentation fault? 

The limitation with my module is i cannot pass the pointer, but rather i have an option to pass the address of the memory location to be able to access it at later point of time.

The steps you have mentioned still has crashes. Is there a way I can get out without being crashed.

Comment: Ah! thank you. It was a useful tip and i was able to get around the problem with the machine arch type support.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but I believe there are some inaccuracies in your code which may be the source of your problem:

`data_addr = (uint32_t) &data[16]` is not a good idea, because `uint32_t` may be too small for an address (actually it makes my machine segfault at later execution, because the truncated value is casted back to an invalid address).

`p = (uint32_t *) data_addr` can be safely replaced with `p = (uint32_t *) (data+16)`, since both sides represent addresses (no truncation).

Use `printf("%p", p)` for printing an address, because in the `printf("%#x", data + 16)` you use, `%x` expects and `unsigned int`, which may not have the same size as an address.

Use `printf("%#x", (unsigned int) ...)` for printing an `uint32_t`, because `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, which may not have the same size as an `uint32_t`.

Here is a corrected version of your program which does not causes a segfault on my machine:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     unsigned char data[100];
     unsigned int i;
     uint32_t *p;

     for (i = 0; i != 100; i++)
         data[i] = i;

     p = (uint32_t *)  (data + 16);
     printf("Value = %#x Address %p\n", (unsigned int) *p, data + 16);
     return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something on these lines:

```
p = *(uint32_t **) &data_addr;
```

(as seen in "[Carmack's hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)") basically you take the address of `data_addr`, cast it to `pointer to pointer of uint32_t`, and then de-reference it, obtaining a `pointer to uint32_t`, the datatype of `p`.

The caveats mentioned by John Kugelman in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29850278/855869) obviously apply.