# Does pointer equality imply integer equality?

Tags: c, pointers, posix, language-lawyer, c11

For `int *a, int *b`, does `a == b` imply `(intptr_t)a == (intptr_t)b`?  I know that it's true for example on a modern X86 CPU, but does the C standard or POSIX or any other standard give a guarantee for this?

Comment: Yes, given that intptr_t is always guaranteed to be big enough to hold a pointer... Relevant link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410294/what-is-intptr-t-is-it-a-type-for-integer-or-pointer?

Comment: @AlexG It is not enough to imply the integer equality. `==` is true for pointers if these point to the same object. Which can be interpreted differently, if we, say, have two different memory mappings of the same object.

Comment: @EugeneSh. integer equality would be written as (*a) == (*b). OP asked for a == b thus address equality.

Comment: @AlexG I am using OP's terminology as is. The "integer equality" in this context is the equality of the pointer numerical values.

Comment: On an old Intel 80286 processor using a segmented memory model, this would not hold. For example, `(int *)0x00010001 == (int *)0x00000011` would be true.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Would it? Can you prove?

Comment: @AlexG, EugeneSh. Yes, the "integer equality" terminology in the heading is a bit confusing, but it should be clear from the post that I mean the equality of the pointers converted to an integer.

Comment: Prove? No. Remember, yes. I even wrote code to "canonicalize" pointers to avoid such problems.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Hm. That's weird. Even given my first comment I would not think it could be in reality...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Hey, wait. It's the opposite of what the OP is asking. Would `(intptr_t)(int *)0x00010001 == (intptr_t)(int *)0x00000011` ?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Me too! I wrote code to canonicalize them with the smallest possible offset, and to canonicalize with the largest possible offset, depending on in which way I wanted increment room in the resulting pointer.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker But, ... was it true (e.g. in Microsoft's C) that differently configured `far` pointers referencing the same memory location **compared true** without being canonicalized first? That I don't recall.  If those pointers didn't compare true before being converted to integers, then they don't apply to this question. Maybe *huge* ones would have compared true but not *far* ones?

Comment: @Kaz The compiler would normally canonicalise pointers before comparison, but not before some other operations (like cast to an integer).

Comment: Note that `(u)intptr_t` are _optional_ types - not guaranteed to exist.  So integer equality can not well be access on all machines.  An alternative is `memcmp()` - yet that may be problematic due to padding.

Comment: Back then, there was no `uintptr_t`; that's a more recent thing. We just had `int` and `long`. I do not remember exactly how my compiler treated casts of far pointers to long. Memory fades with age...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker As I recall, `FAR char *` to `long` was a bit copy.  `1234:5678 ==> 0x12345678`

Comment: @n.m.: Converting pointers to canonical form is very expensive on the 8088, and the only time I would see it as useful is when converting a `far*` to a `huge*`.  Any `huge*` should already be in canonical form, and any two `far*` that identify portions of the same object should have matching segments.  I can't see any good reason code shouldn't use pointers where one of the above conditions wouldn't hold.

Comment: @chux Right! Which was the basis for writing the canonicalization code.

Answer (score 10):

This is not guaranteed by the C standard. (This answer does not address whether POSIX or other standards say about `intptr_t`.) What the C standard (2011, draft N1570) says about `intptr_t` is:

> 7.20.1.4 1 The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: **intptr_t**

As a theoretical proof, one counterexample is a system that has 24-bit addresses, where the high eight bits are unused, but the available integer types are 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32-bit. In this case, the C implementation could make `intptr_t` a 32-bit integer, and it could convert a pointer to `intptr_t` by copying the 24-bit address into the 32-bit integer and neglecting the high eight bits. Those bits might be left over from whatever was lying around previously. When the `intptr_t` value is converted back to a pointer, the compiler discards the high eight bits, which results in the original address. In this system, when `a == b` is evaluated for pointers `a` and `b`, the compiler implements this by comparing only the 24 bits of the address. Thus, if `a` and `b` point to the same object `a == b` will be true, but `(intptr_t) a == (intptr_t) b` may evaluate to false because of the neglected high bits. (Note that, strictly, `a` and `b` should be pointers to `void` or should be converted to pointers to `void` before being converted to `intptr_t`.)

Another example would be a system which uses some base and offset addressing. In this system, a pointer might consist of 16 bits that specify some base address and 16 bits that specify an offset. The base might be in multiples of 64 bytes, so the actual address represented by  *base* and *offset* is *base*•64 + *offset*. In this system, if pointer `a` has base 2 and offset 10, it represents the same address as pointer `b` with base 1 and offset 74. When comparing pointers, the compiler would evaluate *base*•64 + *offset* for each pointer and compare the results, so `a == b` evaluates to true. However, when converting to `intptr_t`, the compiler might simply copy the bits, thus producing 131,082 (2•65536 + 10) for `(intptr_t) a` and 65,610 (1•65536 + 74) for `(intptr_t) b`. Then `(intptr_t) a == (intptr_t) b` evaluates to false. But the rule that converting an `intptr_t` back to a pointer type produces the original pointer still holds, as the compiler will simply copy the bits again.

Comment: Detail about "the rule that converting an intptr_t back to a pointer type produces the original pointer still holds" -  Hmmm, is not the C spec  that the round trip pointer - integer - pointer only produces a "result will compare equal to the original pointer", not necessarily the same original bit pattern even in this   example?

Comment: With regard to your second example, compilers for the Intel 8086 generally had two kinds of 32-bit pointers which represented physical address `seg*16 + offset`, and each kind had a constraint: all `large` pointers identifying portions of the same object had to specify the same segment (individual objects were limited to 65,520 bytes), and all `huge` pointers had to have an offset in the range 0-15.  Still, your example for a system with pointers that are narrower than `uintptr_t` matches what I would have said if you hadn't beaten me to it.

Comment: @chux: For the second example, if a compiler would regard two pointers with different bit patterns as equal, and if conversion to/from integer type kept the bit patterns, then converting two equal pointers with different bit patterns would yield different integers, but converting those different integers back to pointers would yield pointers that--like the originals--had different bit patterns but compare equal.

Comment: @supercat [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726231/does-pointer-equality-imply-integer-equality/50726756?noredirect=1#comment88465143_50726756), but what if "conversion to/from integer type kept the bit patterns" way only "to integer" and the from integer back to pointer conversion lacked bit same bit-pattern (as unicorn-ish as that sounds), the resultant pointer would still compare equal, yet not same as original.  On both to/from conversions, the _same bit pattern_ or not attribute is independently implementation dependent.  This answers last sentence seems to imply otherwise.

Comment: @chux: Yes, a counterexample could be that the round-trip produces a pointer with a different bit representation but that compares equal to the original. (That does suggest the implementation is normalizing the oointer when converting to integer, which is likely to cause the integers to compare equal. It is legal for an implementation to behave otherwise, but practical implementations are less likely to be weird about it.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Am I correct in thinking that nothing in the Standard would forbid an implementation where converting any integer value that isn't a null pointer constant to a pointer yielded bit pattern 0x00000001, if the pointer equality operator treated such pointers as equal to all other pointers?  Such behavior would obviously be obtuse and useless, but the Standard makes no effort to forbid obtuse and useless behaviors since competent people writing quality compilers should have the common sense not to behave obtusely.

Comment: @supercat: `==` applied to pointers cannot yield true for all non-NULL operands. Pointers to different objects must compare as different (except that a pointer to one past the end of an array may compare equal to a pointer to the object that happens to immediately follow it in memory).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Does the Standard say that a round-trip conversion of a pointer to an object yields a pointer to an object, or merely that round-trip conversion of a `void*` yields a `void*` that *compares equal* to the original?

Comment: @supercat: 6.3.2 1 sound round trips from a pointer to an object type to a pointer to void compares equal. 7.20.1.4 1 says round trips from pointers to void to `intptr_t` compare equal. One can compound these (which, strictly, should be done by `(intptr_t) (void *) foo` rather than just `(intptr_t) foo`) so that one round trip nests inside the other. The 6.5.9 6 tells us that pointers that compare equal do in fact point to the same object, except for the one-beyond-last-element-coincides-with-next-object exception. That loophole may be a defect in the standard, but the intent is clear.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The Standard may intend that pointer equality be an equivalence relation, but I don't think compilers always treat it as one.  You may be right that the Standard might not allow compilers to be quite as obtuse as I was suggesting, but the fact remains that it relies upon compiler writers' judgment as to what if anything code may *do* with a pointers produced by an integer-to-pointer cast other than compare them.  Such a cast could either yield a pointer to an object or a pointer just past the previous object, and there would be no way for code to distinguish those cases...

Comment: ...using actions whose behavior would be defined in both of them.

Comment: "Those bits might be left over from whatever was lying around previously." This would imply that C somehow allowed partial initialization/assignment of variables. A less unlikely case would be something like the compiler using one byte of the result as a padding byte to ensure alignment. Still, I don't think any real-world system behaves like that. This is all implementation-defined mostly because the standard doesn't specify the binary format of pointers. In a real world system, it would only make sense to compare two `intptr_t` if you do know the implementation-defined format.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to specify all the guarantees that should be upheld by quality implementations on commonplace platforms, the Standard instead seeks to avoid mandating any guarantees that might be expensive or problematic on any conceivable platform unless they are so valuable as to justify any possible cost.  The authors expected (reasonably at the time) that quality compilers for platforms which could offer stronger guarantees at essentially no cost would do so, and thus saw need to explicitly mandate things compilers were going to do anyway.

If one looks at what the actual guarantee offered by the Standard, it's absurdly wimpy.  It specifies that converting a void* to a uintptr_t and then back to a void* will yield a pointer that may be compared to the original, and that the comparison will report that the two pointers are equal.  It says nothing about what will happen if code does anything else with round-trip-converted pointer.  A conforming implementation could perform integer-to-pointer conversions in a way that ignores the integer value (unless it is a Null Pointer Constant) and yields some arbitrary bit pattern that doesn't match any valid or null pointer, and then have its pointer-equality operators report "equal" whenever either operand holds that special bit pattern.  No quality implementation should behave in such a fashion of course, but nothing in the Standard would forbid it.

In the absence of optimizations, it would be reasonable to assume that on any platform which uses "linear" pointers that are the same size as `uintptr_t`, quality compilers will process conversion of pointers to `uintptr_t` such that conversion of equal pointers will yield the same numeric value, and that given `uintptr_t u;`, if `u==(uintptr)&someObject`, then `*(typeOfObject*)u` may be used to access `someObject`, at least between the time the address of `someObject` was converted to a `uintptr_t` and the next time `someObject` is accessed via other means, without regard for how `u` came to hold its value.  Unfortunately, some compilers are too primitive to recognize that conversion of an address to a `uintptr_t` would suggest that a pointer formed from a `uintptr_t` might be capable of identifying the same object.

Comment: If `u == (uintptr_t) &someObject`, then `* (typeOfObject *) u` necessarily compares equal to `&someObject` and hence may be used to access `someObject` because of the rule about round-trip conversions. The result of `(uintptr_t) &someObject` is a value, not an lvalue or object. If `u` equals it, then the value of `u` is the same value—a value is characterized only by itself; it is not distinguished by the fact that it is the value of some object. Hence `(typeOfObject *) u` is the same as `(typeOfObject *) (uintptr_t) &SomeObject`, and the round-trip rule says that is equal to `&SomeObject`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The fact that two pointers compare equal does not imply that both may be used to access the same object.  It's certainly possible for a pointer-integer-pointer round-trip conversion to yield something that isn't a pointer to an object (e.g. if the original pointed just past the last object in memory).  It would certainly make sense that if the original was a pointer to an object, the result of the conversion should be likewise, but I see nothing in the Standard that actually *says* that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Given something like `extern int x,y; void foo(void) { x=1; ((int volatile*)(uintptr_t)&y)[1] = 2; return x;}`; should a compiler be required to allow for the possibility of the second statement setting `x` to 2 [if e.g. the caller had checked that `(uintptr_t)(1+&y)==(uintptr_t)&x`]?  Personally, I doubt that integer-to-pointer conversions are sufficiently common that treating the results of such conversions as Pointers of Officially Unknowable Provenance, at least when `volatile`, would be a significant burden, but I don't think the Standard requires such treatment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Slight code correction: `int test(void){ x=1; *(int volatile*)(uintptr_t)(1+&y) = 2; return x; }`.  If an implementation specifies a means of pointer-to-integer conversions that will always yield the same value for any given pointer, a programmer could ensure that the function would only get called if it should store 2 to `*(int volatile*)(uintptr_t)x`.

Comment: `((int volatile*)(uintptr_t)&y)[1]` is prohibited by the last sentence of 6.5.6 8, since `((int volatile*)(uintptr_t)&y)` is a pointer to `y` (or, worse, is a pointer to one beyond the last element of the array preceding `y`), so the expression evaluates to `y[1]`, which is `*(y+1)`, which is the prohibited evaluation.

Comment: It may be that `*(int volatile *)(uintptr_t)(1+&y) = 2` is a defect in the standard. Certainly the intent of 6.5.6 8 is that you should not do this. Aside from the last-element-coincides-with-next-object exception, 6.5.9 6 tells us that two pointers to object types that compare equal are pointers to the same object (it is an “if and only if”, so not only does it tells us that pointers to the same object are equal, but pointers that are equal are pointers to the same object).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: My point is that the Standard doesn't specify any cases where an integer-to-pointer conversion would be guaranteed to yield a pointer to an object.  The language of the Standard is a bit clumsy in its definitions of "object" and addresses.  For example, given `struct s1 {int x1[2][1],y1;}; struct s2 { int x2[1][2],y2;}; union { struct s1 v1; struct s2 v2;} u;`, are `u.v1.y1` and `u.v1.y2` "the same object"?

Comment: Yes, they are the same object (assuming they landed in the same place). Per 3.15, an object is a region of storage. I disagree; the round-trip requirement specifies that a `intptr_t` that resulted from a conversion from a pointer yields a pointer that is equal to the original, and this is necessarily a pointer to the same object (aside from issues with one-beyond-the-last-element).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I meant `u.v2.y2`, since `u.v1` doesn't have a `y2` member.  Would they be the same object if e.g. one structure had used type `unsigned` in place of `signed`?  Also, if they're the same object, does that mean that after `struct s1 *p1 = &u.v1; struct s2 *p2 = &u.v2;`, both `p1->y1` and `p2->y2` would be the same object?  Both gcc and clang would assume they can't be.